# How can I get pass value from controller back to directive's template attribute in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an AngularJS directive as shown below.
In the associated controller, I compute the value of a variable `text` as `"SomeText"`. I want this text to replace `Hello World!!` in the `template` attribute of the directive. How can I do it?

My HTML:

```
<myp-directive myarg="myObject"></myp-directive>
```

My Directive:

```
myApp.directive('mypDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myarg: '='
      },
      controller: 'DirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: 'Hello World!!'
    };
  }
);
```

My Controller:

```
myApp.controller('DirectiveCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.prediction;}, function (newVal, oldVal)
    {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal !== null){
          var text = "SomeText";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use the `controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl'` configuration you can simply assign `"SomeText"` as a variable of the controller (self) and it will be available in the template.

Pascal Precht wrote quite an extensive [explanation about controllerAs](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html).

Controller

```
myApp.controller('DirectiveCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    self.text = "Hello World!!";
    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.prediction;}, function (newVal, oldVal)
    {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal !== null){
          self.text = "SomeText";
        }
    });
});
```

Directive

```
myApp.directive('mypDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myarg: '='
      },
      controller: 'DirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '{{directiveCtrl.text}}'
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use scope. Bind the text 'Hello World' to a scope variable (*data*) and bind it in the template as {{data}}. The change the value of the scope variable from the controller.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/ocwujdvu/)

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('mypDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myarg: '='
    },
    controller: 'DirectiveCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '{{data}}',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, directiveCtrl) {
      scope.data = "Hello World!!!"
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "Bind the text to Hello World"? Can you please show example with code? I do not want the HTML to know about the internals of the directive or this controller.